# Puzzling.SE job ads?

Tags: feature-request

OK, so a question was posted on Puzzling.SE which was basically a job ad from a publication which wanted someone to write puzzles for them.

It was immediately deleted, presumably job ads are in breach of SE's terms. (?)

But actually that - professional jobs for puzzlers - might be quite a useful service that people here would like.

Given that SE *has* a [commercial jobsite arm](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), would it be possible for us to direct people looking for professional puzzlers in that direction, and get the jobs they post to show up here on p.SE?

I'm not expecting it'll happen very often, but:

- it makes sense to take advantage of it when it does,
- it could add to the 'professional puzzling' tone of the site,
- it could make a few $$ for SE, which would help to pay our bandwidth bills,
- since SE is already doing this (or something like it) for the tech-sites, I'm guessing it might be pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Something to consider is that some people define "expert" is "published/professional". I personally feel one does not need to be employed as a Z to be an expert of Z. But for the rest, having some channels like this open would _help P.SE_ (and its usership) take those final steps into more popular legitmacy.

Answer (score 3):

[The question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/looking-to-add-a-puzzle-column-for-my-bi-monthly-magazine) was deleted via spam flag. We [discourage posts that are purely promotional](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) because they aren't useful questions. You see, [real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). (I suppose you could say that if someone offers a job as a question, someone could answer by submitting an application or something. But I hope you see that's not really the same thing.)

We *do* have a Careers business. At least for the moment, it focuses entirely on programming jobs. We've been very careful to make sure that our [job matching service](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about) not interfere with the main purpose of Stack Overflow: helping programmers get the answers to programming questions. If someone were to post a similar question linking to our own product, it'd be rightly deleted as quickly as people saw it.

At the moment, we aren't too worried about making money off of this site. You'll notice we don't have advertising turned on here, for instance. The truth is a [small percentage of the sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) account for the bulk of network traffic and we are comfortable limiting advertising to those sites. We'd prefer to let other sites on the network grow without impediment.

In this particular case, I'm not sure the "opportunity" was really a great one. When I followed the link provided, my search ended on a deleted reddit user account.

Comment: OK Jon, well thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity (not that I intend anything in particular): Would a generally formed question posting as "How do I find able puzzle-smiths?" be a valid or would it be deleted as well? Such a question could have a multitude of answers from "*Take me, Me, ME!*" to "Site XY is where you want to post positions."