# Should I delete my poorly-written puzzle?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wrote this puzzle, which has been downvoted. I agree that it isn't a good puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7764/how-many-letters-are-in-the-answer-to-this-question

Should I go ahead and delete the question, or is there any value to the community if I leave it? I'm not planning on editing it because I think the puzzle is fundamentally an assumption puzzle, and a cheeky one at that, so it might not be salvagable.

Comment: How about accepting my answer and then leaving it there to show how bad it is? It can be used educationally as a poorly written question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should delete it. One of our goals as a community is to create a [collection of high-quality puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1699/294). Leaving a bad puzzle will add more noise, making it more difficult to find high-quality puzzles.

Comment: I agree, go ahead and delete it. This will prevent you from accruing more negative reputation in the short term. And the system will automatically delete it anyway after some time (60 or 90 days, I think) for being closed with a negative score.

Comment: I tried deleting the question, and got a message that since the post has answers, I can't delete it on my own. Is it worth trying to get a moderator to delete it, or should I just let it sit?

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. Just leave it then, let the automated system clean it up for you later.